# Disable a functionality (ax-modification) by company on AX 2012 R3

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I am developing a pretty complex modification of the standard invoicing process, it implies different classes, tables, etc. Also added my configuration key, security, roles, etc. Like a new module.

How and which tools can I use to disable such feature for a certain company and let it enabled by default for the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to create a non-company specific parameters table and add/remove companies that way. Then via code check the parameters table if it should be enabled.

If the companies are in different countries, you could use the `CountryRegionCodes` property (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404126.aspx)

Comment: I was thinking something similar with a multi-selection lookup and a new static Boolean method. It could work on a code level, but how can I hide related menu items on the module menu?

Comment: Finally we will hide the menu items by user's role.